# can we call constructor in another function of the same contract in solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, constructor, function

can we call constructor in another function of the same contract in solidity ? Curious, Kindly reply asap. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to call the constructor because it is not part of the runtime bytecode.

However it is possible to call a function from the constructor and then it will be available for use at any time.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: ISC

pragma solidity 0.8.14;

contract Test {
     uint256 public x;

     constructor(uint256 _x) {
          _initialize(_x);
     }

     function foo(uint256 bb) public {
          _initialize(bb);
     }

     function _initialize(uint256 _a) internal {
          x = _a;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the constructor of other contracts is only possible in this way.

```
contract ERC20{
    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;
    string public _name;
    string public _symbol;
    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
        _balances[msg.sender] = 1000000000E18;
    }
}

contract YToken is ERC20 {
    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) ERC20(name_, symbol_) {
        
    }
}
```

as @Ismael has stated it is not possible to call a constructor of an already deployed contract because it is not part of the runtime bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use constructors, variables, functions, etc of other contracts of same smart contract. e.g.-

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT    
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
    
contract c1 {
    uint a;
    constructor(){
        a=100;
    }
}

contract c2 is c1{
    function getA() public view returns(uint){
        return a;
    }
}
```

use function of another contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT    
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
    
contract c1 {
    uint a;
    constructor(){
        a=100;
    }
    function changeA(uint _a) public{
        a=_a;
    }
}

contract c2 is c1{
    function getA() public view returns(uint){
        return a;
    }
    function change(uint _a) public{
        changeA(_a);
    }
}
```

reference docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/contracts.html#inheritance